# Como eu limito a rotação de prefabs em 2 eixos na Unity?

Tags: unity3d

Preciso que um prefab para de girar quando atinge 2 valores positivos em Y. No caso quando atingir 65º. Meu código está assim, só que não está funcionando.

```
 private float m_MaxYRotation = 65f;    
    private float m_MinYRotation = -65f;  
    private float velocity = 3;

    private void Update()   {
        var eulerRotation = transform.rotation.eulerAngles;

        eulerRotation.y = Camera.main.transform.eulerAngles.y;

        if (eulerRotation.y < 270)
            eulerRotation.y += 360;

       eulerRotation.y = Mathf.Clamp(eulerRotation.y, 180 + m_MinYRotation, 180 + m_MaxYRotation);

        transform.localEulerAngles = (Vector3.down * eulerRotation.y  * velocity);
```

Answer (score 1):

utiliza a função Mathf.Clamp();
Exemplo:

```
Vector3 move;
float valormin = 0;
float valormax = 90;
move.x = Mathf.Clamp(move.x, valormin, valormax);
```

Este exemplo faria com que um vector3 num valor de x seria entre 0 e 90

Answer (score 0):

Primeiramente você deve pegar a rotação em Y do objeto e verificar o valor da rotação com o limite estabelecido, onde caso ele não ultrapasse o valor maximo estabelecido, o objeto pode continuar recebendo a rotação.

A logica ficaria assim:

```
if(transform.eulerAngles.y > 65f){
 debug.log("Passou de 65ª");
}else{
  //Codigo que continua atribuindo a rotação no objeto.
}
```